# Gronwall's Lemma with an additive term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $V(t)$ is a real function of $t\in \mathbb{R}$, differentiable on $t>t_0$, and satisfies

$$\dot{V}(t) \le -\alpha V(t) + \beta \sqrt{V(t)}\quad \forall t>t_0,$$

where $\alpha,\beta$ are two positive scalars. Can I use a Gronwall-like argument to say that $V(t)\le W(t)$ for $t\ge t_0$, where $W(t)$ satisfies the corresponding differential equation,

$$\dot{W}(t) = -\alpha W(t) + \beta \sqrt{W(t)}\quad \forall t>t_0$$

and $V(t_0)\le W(t_0)$? If so, can you point out a reference for such a result?

Comment: The change of variable $X(t)=\alpha\sqrt{V(t)}-\beta$ reduces this to classical Gronwall.

Comment: But I am not sure: $V(t)$ may be zero for some $t>t_0$, which would make $X(t)$ non differentiable, and therefore Gronwall's Lemma would not apply anymore. Is the inequality still valid if $V(t)$ hits zero at some point?

Comment: Alternative approach: Show that $Y(t)=\left(\alpha\sqrt{V(t)}-\beta\right) \cdot\mathrm e^{\alpha t/2}$ is nonincreasing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that. What happens if $Y(t)$ is nonincreasing?

Comment: If $Z$ is to $W$ what $Y$ is to $V$, then $Z$ is constant hence $V(t_0)\leqslant W(t_0)$ implies $Y(t_0)\leqslant Z(t_0)$ which implies $Y(t)\leqslant Y(t_0)\leqslant Z(t_0)=Z(t)$, thus, $V(t)\leqslant W(t)$.